# Count the total number of unique rows in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data = { 
        'node1': [2,2,2,3,3,5,5],
        'node2': [8,16,22,5,25,10,77],
        'weight': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1], }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['node1','node2','weight'])

print df["node1"].value_counts()
```

This gives the output as :

```
2 3
3 2
5 2
```

But I desire the answer `3` as that is the number of unique values of rows in column `node1`

Comment: Use `df['node1'].nunique()`?

Comment: thanks I couldnt find this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Zero

```
df['node1'].nunique()
```

This works for my answer